# Tcl echo file contents to transcript

Tags: tcl, cat

i'm using some simulator that uses Tcl for transcript commands (Questa sim)
i want to echo file content like "cat" command in unix.

can it be done in one line command at tcl? is it possible to "cat" just the 5 first lines of file

Answer (score 4):

In one line

```
puts [read [open data.dat r]]
```

OR step by step..

```
set handle [open data.dat r]
puts [read $handle]
close $handle
```

Answer (score 2):

To open a file and echo its contents to standard output (just like `cat`), do this:

```
set f [open $filename]
fcopy $f stdout
close $f
```

To just do the first five lines (which is just like `head -5`), use this procedure:

```
proc head {filename {lineCount 5}} {
    set f [open $filename]
    for {set i 0} {$i < $lineCount} {incr i} {
        if {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
            puts $line
        }
    }
    close $f
}
```

It takes more work because it's more complex to detect line endings than it is to just ship bytes around.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the following code, to read 5 lines at a time from a given file.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set prev_count -1
set fp [open "input-file.txt" "r"]
set num_lines [split [read $fp] \n]
for {set i 4} {$i < [llength $num_lines]} { incr i 5} {
   set line_5 [lrange $num_lines [incr prev_count] $i ]
   set prev_count $i
   puts "$line_5\n\n"
}
```